# How to create a regex in Javascript + jquery

Tags: javascript, regex

How to create a regex in javascript jquery for the below
(5 chars) - (5 chars) - (4 digits) - (2 digits) - (2 digits) - (1 digit)
e.g., ABCDE-ABCDE-1234-12-12-1

```js
var txt = 'ABCDE-ABCDE-1234-12-12-1';
    
var re1 = '((?:[a-z][a-z]+))'; // Word 1
var re2 = '.*?'; // Non-greedy match on filler
var re3 = '((?:[a-z][a-z]+))'; // Word 2

var p = new RegExp(re1 + re2 + re3,["i"]);
var m = p.exec(txt);

if (m != null) {
    var word1 = m[1];
    var word2 = m[2];
    document.write("(" + word1.replace(/</,"&lt;") + ")" + "(" + word2.replace(/</,"&lt;") + ")" + "\n");
}
```

Comment: The second argument to `new RegExp` should be a string, not an array

Comment: Is `.split("-")` an option for you?

Comment: how about this `txt.split('-').map(w=>`(${w})`).join('-')`

Comment: Also please give example of inputs and expected output. For example you do not have any `<>` in your string

Comment: your requirement does not explain your code either regex.

Comment: do you need something like this `/\w{5}-\w{5}-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d/g`?

Comment: Yes if i have to generate the regex for the scenario (5 chars) - (5 chars) - (4 digits) - (2 digits) - (2 digits) - (1 digit) how can i do that then

Comment: you can use `/(?:\w{5}-){2}\d{4}-(?:\d{2}-){2}\d/i`.

Comment: Thank you Teiem you response is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex for the pattern like `'ABCDE-ABCDE-1234-12-12-1'` can be as follow

```
var patt = '[A-Z]{5}-[A-Z]{5}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{1}'
var patt = new RegExp(patt);
var m = patt.exec('ABCDE-ABCDE-1234-12-12-1');
```